# Is there a way to get a list of monthly datetime intervals [(timestart_of_month1, timeend_of_month1), ...] using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, intervals

The only thing I could achieve is to get intervals between start dates of months:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.interval_range(
    start=pd.Timestamp('2021-01-01 00:00:00'), 
    end=pd.Timestamp('2021-03-31 23:59:59'), 
    freq='MS'
)

# 2021-01-01 00:00:00 - 2021-02-01 00:00:00
# 2021-02-01 00:00:00 - 2021-03-01 00:00:00
```

And to get intervals between end dates of months:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.interval_range(
    start=pd.Timestamp('2021-01-01 00:00:00'), 
    end=pd.Timestamp('2021-03-31 23:59:59'), 
    freq='MS'
)

# 2021-01-31 00:00:00 - 2021-02-28 00:00:00
# 2021-02-28 00:00:00 - 2021-03-31 00:00:00
```

But all I want is to get simple monthly intervals:

```
# 2021-01-01 00:00:00 - 2021-01-31 23:59:59
# 2021-02-01 00:00:00 - 2021-02-28 23:59:59
# 2021-03-01 00:00:00 - 2021-03-31 23:59:59
```

I want to achieve it in a very neat way without subtracting one second, etc.

Comment: But isn't the neatest way to get your very particular definition of the edge to just subtract off 1 second? I mean why doesn't the right edge end at 2021-01-31 23:59:59.999 or 2021-01-31 23:59:59.999999999; timestamps are defined with nanosecond resolution

Comment: @ALollz well, I am not sure, why the right edge does not end with 2021-01-31 23:59:59.999999999; The interval shows [2021-01-01 00:00:00 - 2021-02-01 00:00:00). So, the interval should not include 2021-02-01 00:00:00. But when I do print(my_interval.right), it prints 2021-02-01 00:00:00 instead of 23:59:59.999999999